# Hashtable insertion order

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I am doing an assignment and it requires use of a hashtable. We need to store numbers in a hashtable, and then return the index of the location of 2 numbers that sum to a given target. So if the target is 8, and theres a 3 and a 5 in there, i need to return the indicies. I have written it with array no problem, but I dont understand the location of where numbers go when being inserted in the hashtable.

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    numbers.put("one", 1);
    numbers.put("two", 2);
    numbers.put("three", 3);
    numbers.put("four", 4);
    numbers.put("five", 5);
    numbers.put("six", 6);
```

This, in debugging mode, shows that the insertion all said and done is:
{five = 5, six = 6, two = 2, one = 1, three = 3, four = 4}

Why is it like this? We learned that hastables store data as the following:
1%11 (where 11 is the size of the hashtable which is default in this case) = 1 and store it at position 1.
2%11 would give position at index 2.
and so on...
14%11 would give position 3 (index 3) and if there is a collision to do linear probing or quadratic probing. Im confused on how the built in hashtable function stores my data. Thanks!!

EDIT:
Lets say i do Hashtable Integer, Integer instead

Comment: The hashtable will be calling `getHashCode` on your keys - which are strings, not integers. It doesn't really make sense to talk about "indexes" of entries in a hashtable. It's doesn't have a *defined* order.

Comment: Re: edit, then the hashtable will call still `getHashCode` on your keys, but `Integer.getHashCode` returns the value of the int it's wrapping. I don't know the internals of `HashTable` - you'll likely see a *different* order, but it may not be simple numerical order. In general, `HashTable` makes no guarantee regarding ordering.